# R graphic 'text' package 'adj' parameter order wrong incorrect reversed?

Tags: r, text, graphics, manual

I believe R core package `graphics` `text` function's `adj` parameter is incorrectly [described in the manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) and would be grateful if someone could confirm this before I submit a [bug report](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html).

`adj` text:

> adj allows adjustment of the text with respect to (x, y). Values of 0,
>   0.5, and 1 specify left/bottom, middle and right/top alignment, respectively.

Since text controls these labels and not the points which have already been plotted, I can't see how "with respect to x,y" can mean anything other than "in this direction relative to their points".

However the order is reversed: 0,0 (left & bottom) is top & right; 1,1 (right & top) is left and bottom.

Reproducible example:

```
tens = 1:10
plot(tens, tens, xlab = "adj 0,0 left/bottom")
text(tens, tens, labels = letters[tens], adj = c(0,0))
plot(tens, tens, xlab = "adj 0.5,0.5 middle")
text(tens, tens, labels = letters[tens], adj = c(0.5,0.5))
plot(tens, tens, xlab = "adj 1,1 right/top")
text(tens, tens, labels = letters[tens], adj = c(1,1))
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tend to think of "0=left" as left-aligned, meaning it spans to the right of the point. Similarly, "1=right" is right-aligned. You aren't wrong, it can be confusing.

Comment: that's a reasonably logical interpretation of the situation though I feel it isn't intuitive (or arguably even 'correct') based solely on the rubric. "Left with respect to X" surely should be on the left of X. Personally I'd intuitively interpret left-aligned to be on the left hand side per MS word layout but that's semantics since the package authors don't use that term. That you've confirmed the ambiguity suggests the text could be clearer, regardless of whether it's technically correct or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For generations of typesetters, left justification has been aligning the type with the *right* edge of the frame so that the lines are aligned on the *left* edge of the printed page. History often gets us turned around.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'm currently discussing this on the r-package-devel mailing list and this seems to be the source of the issue. However implicitly referencing an invisible typesetting box is rather an obtuse move given documentation is supposed to be explicit and clear. We'll see what the outcome is!